# What does the landing time mean in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

There is a section called "landing time" in the DAG view on the web console of airflow.

An example screen shot taken from airbnb's blog:

[image]

But what does it mean? There is no definition in the documents or in their repository.

Comment: Looks like it's a DAG.  https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dags.html

Comment: Shown in the documentation here.  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/DAGs+UI

Comment: Source: function landing_times in https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/views.py .  Looks like it might show when recent jobs completed.

Answer (score 26):

Since the existing answer here wasn't totally clear, and this is the top hit for "airflow landing time" I went to the chat archives and found the original answer being referenced here:

> Maxime Beauchemin @mistercrunch Jun 09 2016 11:12
> it's the number of hours after the time the scheduling period ended
> take a schedule_interval='@daily' run for 2016-01-01 that finishes at 2016-01-02 03:52:00
> landing time is 3:52

https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow/archives/2016/06/09

It seems the Y axis is in hours, and the negative landing times are a result of running jobs manually so they finish hours before they "should have finished" based on the schedule.

Comment: I am wondering if this is entirely accurate. I see jobs with landing time of 5 hours when the job ended at 11:00 in the morning. That is because the job did not start immediately after the scheduling period ended since it had upstream dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

I directly asked the author Maxime. His answer was `landing_time` is when the job completes minus when the job should have started (for airflow, it's the end of the scheduled period).

source:
http://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow
It is a good place to get help and Maxine is very nice and helpful. But the answers are not persistent..

Comment: I wonder whether the word 'minutes' is a typo of 'minus'. Even so, I can't quite make sense of your description. Do you mind elaborating it a little bit more?

Comment: I think op meant -> (the time when the job completes) - (the time when the job should have started). So it's the variance in order to see if the job has been executed on schedule or not.

Answer (score 2):

For me its easier to understand `landing_time` using an example.
So let's say we have a dag scheduled to run daily at `0 0 * * *`. This dag has 2 tasks that execute sequentially:

`first_task >> second_task`

The *first_task* starts at 00:00 and 10 seconds and finishes after 5 minutes at 00:05:10.
The landing_time for first_task will be **5 mins and 10 seconds**.

The *second_task* starts execution at 00:07:00 minute and finishes after 2 minutes. The landing_time for the second_task would be **9 minutes.**

So we just delete from the task end_time the dag *execution_date*.
Thanks to @Kalinde Pride for commenting and pointing me to the only source of truth, the [airflow code base](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/www/views.py#L3242).

I usually use landing_time as a measure and metric of the performance of the whole airflow system. For example increase in landing_times in the first tasks seems to mean that scheduler is under heavy load or we should adapt task parallelization (through airflow.cfg).

Comment: What if landing times are negative? how do you explain that?

Comment: Incorrect. In this code (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/www/views.py#L3242), landing time is calculated as task end time - scheduled time. So in your example, first_task landing time is 5 minutes 10 seconds, and second_task landing time is 9 minutes.

Answer (score -4):

Landing Times: Total time spent including retries.